# Syntax error fixing devise to not use email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

```
class UpdateIndexOnUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def up
   sql = 'DROP INDEX index_users_on_email'
   sql << ' ON users' if Rails.env == 'production' # Heroku pg
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
 end
end
```

Getting a syntax error when trying to rake db:migrate on heroku. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Using Postgresql. I should mention it works fine locally.

Edit: The error

```
PG::SyntaxError: Error: syntax error at or near "ON"
Line 1: DROP INDEX index_users_on_email ON users
                                        ^
```

Comment: Would help if you can post the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy thing would be to use rails' helpers and let them take care of datebase specifics:

```
class UpdateIndexOnUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_index :users, :email
  end
end
```

If the index was initially created with a name other than the one that rails would use by default you could do

```
class UpdateIndexOnUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_index :users, :email, :name => 'name_of_index'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Postgresql doesn't support (or need) `ON xxxx` when dropping an index.  The docs don't mention it either:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-dropindex.html

Just specifying the index name should be fine, though you can qualify it with the schema name which you probably don't need to do if you've got a standard setup.

If you're also using postgresql locally, then presumably it's working because `ON users` is only added when rails env is `production` whereas you're presumably running in `development` locally.